# Fit google maps bounds using vue3-google-map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vuejs3

I am trying to build a Vue component that takes in input an array of gps (lat/lng) data and which have to be drawn on a map using a google maps polyline. It is working until this point. The problem rises when I try to use map.fitbounds in order to manage the zoom and center out the map to that polyline. As per vue3-google-map [documentation](https://vue3-google-map.netlify.app/advanced-usage/) I tried to create a ref to the map object with ref="mapRef". Unfortunately in the mounted() hook it seems that I can'f find that object, inside Vue DevTools it will later show up.

```
<template>
<GoogleMap ref="mapRef" api-key="<myapikey>" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" :center="center" :zoom="15">
    <Polyline :options="path" />
</GoogleMap>
</template>

<script>
import {
    defineComponent,
    ref
} from 'vue'
import {
    GoogleMap,
    Polyline
} from 'vue3-google-map'

export default defineComponent({
    components: {
        GoogleMap,
        Polyline
    },
    setup() {
        const mapRef = ref(null)
        return {
            mapRef
        }
    },
    methods: {
        managebounds(path) {
            this.intervalid = setInterval(function () {
                if (!this.bounds && !this.loaded) {
                    if (window.google && window.google.maps && path) {
                        this.bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds()
                        this.loaded = true
                        clearInterval(this.intervalid)
                        console.log("AFTER CLEAR")
                        this.bounds.extend(path.path[0]) //i take the first and last point of the polyline
                        this.bounds.extend(path.path[path.path.length - 1])
                        var extendBy = 0.001;
                        console.log("EXTEND1")
                        var point1 = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
                            this.bounds.getNorthEast().lat() + extendBy,
                            this.bounds.getNorthEast().lng() + extendBy
                        )
                        var point2 = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
                            this.bounds.getSouthWest().lat() - extendBy,
                            this.bounds.getSouthWest().lng() - extendBy
                        )
                        this.bounds.extend(point1);
                        console.log("EXTEND2")
                        this.bounds.extend(point2);
                        console.log("FITTING BOUNDS")
                        this.intervalid = setInterval(function () {
                            if (this.$refs.mapRef.value?.ready) {
                                console.log("LOADED")
                                this.$refs.mapRef.value.map.fitBounds(this.bounds); //here mapRef is undefined
                                clearInterval(this.intervalid)
                            } else {
                                console.log("NOT LOADED")
                            }
                        }, 1000)
                    } else {
                        console.log("OUT")
                    }
                }
            }, 500)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            this.managebounds(this.path)
        })

    },
    data() {
        return {
            path: {
                path: this.gpspath.path,
                strokeColor: this.gpspath.color
            },
            bounds: null,
            loaded: false,
            intervalid: -1
        }
    },
    props: {
        "gpspath": {
            type: [],
            default: [{}]
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Any hint about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read again the Vue documentation about [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties) properties and figured out is was a bad idea trying to build a Method.
I made a function inside the `setup()` hook and called that from my computed data.
The working result is in the following code:

```
setup() {
    const mapRef = ref(null)
    function centermap(start, end){
        if (mapRef.value?.ready) {
            const gmap = mapRef.value.map;
            const api = mapRef.value.api;
            this.bounds = new api.LatLngBounds();
            this.bounds.extend(start);
            this.bounds.extend(end);
            gmap.fitBounds(this.bounds);
        }else{
            console.log("NOT READY")
        }
    }
    return {
        mapRef, centermap
    }
},
computed: {
    path() {
        if(this.gpspath){
            let filteredpath = this.gpspath.path.filter(x=>Math.abs(x.lat)>1)
            if(filteredpath && filteredpath.length>1)
                this.centermap(filteredpath[0], filteredpath[filteredpath.length-1])
            return {
                path: filteredpath,
                strokeColor: this.gpspath.color
            }
        }else{
            return {
                path: [],
                strokeColor: "#ffffff"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem; here is my solution:

Page with map:

```
import { mapFitBounds } from "@/composables/mapFitBounds";

const mapRef = ref(null);
watch(
   () => mapRef.value?.ready,
   (ready) => {
   if (!ready) return;
    mapFitBounds(mapRef, markersArray);
   }
);
```

composables/mapFitBounds.js:

```
export function mapFitBounds(mapRef, markers) {
 let bounds;
 const api = mapRef.value.api;
 const map = mapRef.value.map;

 bounds = new api.LatLngBounds();
 for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i]);
 }
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Typescript "type-safe" compact variant with Vue3 composition API:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
...
const mapRef = ref(null)

watch(
  () => (mapRef.value as any)?.ready,
  (ready) => {
    if (ready) {
      console.log(">>> GoogleMap READY - setting bounds");
      let mapRefVal: any = mapRef.value;
      const gmap = mapRefVal.map;
      const api = mapRefVal.api;
      let bounds = new api.LatLngBounds(center);
      for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(markers[i]);
      }
      gmap.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
);

</script>
```